# Saving info from two edit text from a button click using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to get the text from 2 edittext on one activity to 2 texts views on another activity, using sharedpreferences.
altough i used this method already and sucefully, but it was with just one edittext to one textview.
 
This time i don't know what's wrong because i can't acess the strings i define and only get the default values i put in.
 
Hope u guys can help me
 
Thanks in advance.

first activity:

```
eActname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eACTName);
                eActbud = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eACTBud);
                nameData = getSharedPreferences(namefilename, 0);
                budData = getSharedPreferences(budfilename, 0);
 
                bCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreateActivity);
                bCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Intent o = new Intent(ActivityCreate.this, ActView.class);
                                String[] actstrings = new String[] {
                                                eActname.getText().toString(),
                                                eActbud.getText().toString() };
                                o.putExtra("string", actstrings);
 
                                switch (v.getId()) {
                                case R.id.bCreateActivity:
                                        bCreateClick();
 
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
 
                        private void bCreateClick() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                String namestringData = eActname.getText().toString();
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = nameData.edit();
                                editor.putString("namesharedString", namestringData);
                                editor.commit();
                                String budstringData = eActbud.getText().toString();
                                SharedPreferences.Editor budeditor = budData.edit();
                                budeditor.putString("budsharedString", budstringData);
                                budeditor.commit();
```

and now the code from the second activity:

```
tvActName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvActName);
                tvActBud = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvActBud);
                Intent o = getIntent();
                o.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
                tvActName.setText(o.getStringExtra("text"));
                tvActBud.setText(o.getStringExtra("text"));
                nameData = getSharedPreferences(namefilename, 0);
                budData = getSharedPreferences(budfilename, 0);
                String [] actdataReturned = {nameData.getString("namesharedString", "Error"), budData.getString("budsharedString", "Error")} ;
                
                tvActName.setText(actdataReturned[0]);
                tvActBud.setText(actdataReturned[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write the data to the intent you named it "string" when you read the data you named it "strings".

Comment: it does not solve the problem, i keep getting the default value, because i think it can't access the the string for some reason